# Can sw_urdf_exporter be intalled in ubuntu?

Tags: ros, sw-urdf-exporter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I want to use sw_urdf_exporter  but I see that the installation guide concerns Windows users only. The problem is, I don't have Windows on my computer. Should I compile the source code with a C# compiler other than Visual Studios? Should I run the .exe in VirtualBox?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270446/can-sw_urdf_exporter--be-intalled-in-ubuntu?/) by [SofiaGr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29870/sofiagr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2017-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a plugin to SolidWorks, which currently only runs on Windows, so there are no plans to get it to run on any other system.

---

Originally posted by [brawner](https://answers.ros.org/users/2146/brawner/) with karma: 581 on 2017-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2